# Code coloring does not work in WordPress Stack Exchange site

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, wordpress-se

The code colouring works perfectly on StackOverflow and the other sites. However, I haven't seen any code snippet being coloured in the WordPress Stack Exchange site.

An example: [Alternate post_class on each post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174/alternate-post-class-on-each-post) does not have any code coloured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have enabled code coloring for wordpress - from now on post on the meta specific site for wordpress and we will be sure to see it there.